# Troubles authorizing Twitter Streaming API through Python Twitter Tools

Tags: python, twitter, python-twitter

I've been working with [Python Twitter Tools](http://mike.verdone.ca/twitter/) and haven't had any problems authenticating with the REST API through this library.

But when I try to authenticate with the Streaming API, I get nothing but 401 HTTP Unauthorized errors.

Similar to the [website](https://github.com/sixohsix/twitter#the-twitterstream-class) my code is as follows:

```
stream = TwitterStream(
auth=OAuth(OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_SECRET,
           CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
)

stream.statuses.sample()
```

I've tried:

1. Double checking my Tokens/Keys -- I know they're right because I can authenticate using the same tokens and keys through the same library to the REST API.
2. Double checking my permissions level -- I even purposely changed it to Read, Write & Direct Messages, still doesn't work.
3. Also, I looked on the [Twitter Dev](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth) website and it says that I only need OAuth in order to authenticate with the Streaming API, so I don't think its a problem with that either. I only need access to the public stream, nothing higher than that.
4. Checked that I have the latest version of the library -- I do.

Any suggestions would be helpful! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was an OAuth problem, my clock on my computer was more than [+/-5 minutes](https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/1043) than the Twitter server's and so for authorization reasons, I kept getting a HTTP 401 Error.

Fix: Change your computer's internal clock to match that of Twitter's or change your OAuth timestamp calls.

Issue found in the [python twitter tool's repository issues](https://github.com/sixohsix/twitter/issues/133)

Also, for your reference, [OAuth Troubleshooting](https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/204) -- about 8th point down talks about timestamps.